# How do you create custom asynchronous functions in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I was unsure how node.js was able to realize what functions where async and which were not and how to create a custom async function.

Say I wanted to create a custom asynchronous function. I would be surprised if just because I called my last argument to the async function callback or cb that it would just know its an async function:

```
function f(arg1, callback){
  //do stuff with arg1
  arg1.doStuff()
  //call callback
  callback(null, arg1.result());
}
```

I tried something like that and it did not work async. How do you tell node.js that f is actually async?

Comment: Only native functions (with access to the event loop) are asynchronous. You would need to call one of them. If you aren't using any, there's hardly a reason to make your function asynchronous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NOTE**: this answer was written in 2014, before the existence of `async function`, and before Promises gaining popularity. While the same principles apply as well, I would recommend reading on Promises before trying to get your head around how they relate to "traditional" callback-driven async functions.

---

To create a function that calls its callback asynchronously, you have to use some platform-provided async primitive (typically IO-related) on it - timers, reading from the filesystem, making a request etc.

For example, this function takes a callback argument, and calls it 100ms after:

```
function asyncFn(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback();
  }, 100);
}
```

A possible reason for making a function async when it doesn't need to be, is for API consistency. For example, suppose you have a function that makes a network request, and caches the result for later calls:

```
var cache = null;
function makeRequest(callback) {
  if (!cache) {
    makeAjax(result => {
      cache = result;
      callback(result);
    });
  } else {
    callback(cache);
  }
}
```

The problem is, this function is inconsistent: sometimes it is asynchronous, sometimes it isn't. Suppose you have a consumer like this:

```
makeRequest(result => doSomethingWithResult(result));
doSomethingElse();
```

The `doSomethingElse` function may run before or after the `doSomethingWithResult` function, depending on whether the result was cached or not. Now, if you use an async primitive on the `makeRequest` function, such as [`process.nextTick`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback):

```
var cache = null;
function makeRequest(callback) {
  if(!cache) {
    makeAjax(result => {
      cache = result;
      callback(result);
    });
  } else {
    process.nextTick(() => callback(cache));
  }
}
```

The call is always async, and `doSomethingElse` always runs before `doSomethingWithResult`.

Comment: I would change the name of the function - `async` is confusing with new version of ECMAScript.

Answer (score 6):

Only native functions (with access to the event loop) are asynchronous. You would need to call one of them to get asynchronity for your callback. See [What is a simple example of an asynchronous javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13806695/1048572).

If you aren't using any, there's hardly a reason to make your function asynchronous.

Comment: Just to be clear on your last sentence, you can't _make_ a function asynchronous, right?

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund Only by calling another asynchronous function, such as `setTimeout`, but of course that doesn't make the synchronous parts of the code run in background or something.