# Async function with both sync and async code

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have async function that returns true or false. It looks like following one:

```
class User {
  async canManageGroup(group) {
    if (typeof group === 'number') {
      // group - id
      group = await getGroupById(group)
    } // else group is already loaded from DB

    return this.id === group.manager.id
  }
}
```

If `group` parameter is ID of group then function will make async call to DB, so function  `canManageGroup` will execute asynchronously. But if `group` parameter is group model then function will only call `return this.id === group.manager.id` or it will execute syncronously. Is it good practice to write code in this way? Or I should transform synchronous code to asynchronous?

```
function makeAsync(cb) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(() => resolve(cb())))
}

class User {
  async canManageGroup(group) {
    if (typeof group === 'number') {
      // group - id
      group = await getGroupById(group)
    } // else group is already loaded from DB

    return await makeAsync(() => this.id === group.manager.id)
  }
}
```

Comment: no, don't do the second one ... that's redundant in an `async` function

Comment: Possible resolution: have `canManageGroup` always expect a group (never a group ID); if the caller only has a group ID, then they can call `canManageGroup(await getGroupById(groupId))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to one of the answers you are concerned because of the answer to the question [How do you create custom asynchronous functions in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286887/how-do-you-create-custom-asynchronous-functions-in-node-js/22286961#22286961)

> The problem is, this function is inconsistent: sometimes it is asynchronous, sometimes it isn't. Suppose you have a consumer like this:

In js enviroments like nodejs is common practice that the *callback* that could be executed async, should always be called async, no matter if the actual code was really async.

So you are wondering if the following code will break that common practie.

```
async function doSomething() {
  return true
}

doSomething()
.then(res => {
   console.log(res)
})
```

This is not the case, because here you deal with Promises and a Promise is allowed to be resolve immediatly, the code above is basicly the same as if you would write:

```
Promise.resolve(true)
.then(res => {
   console.log(res)
})
```

The async behaviour is ensured in the chaining part (`then`/`catch`), the callback you pass to the `then`/`catch` will be called async:

```js
async function doSomething() {
  return true
}

console.log('before');

doSomething()
  .then(res => {
    console.log('with in callback')
  })

console.log('after');
```

As you can see the order of the logs is:

> before
>   after
>   with in callback

So this is in the same order you would expect from an *regular* async callback function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first example without problems.

When you use `async`, your function will return a `Promise`. If your code is `sync`, the status of the returned promise will be `resolved` and it is safe to run any promise-related code on it (`then`, `catch`, etc).

For example:

```js
async function truePromise() {
  return true;
}

truePromise().then(function(value){
  console.log("Promise value:", value);
});
```

Just works :)

**Should you do it?**

Yes. It is okay and works okay thanks to the `async` keyword.

What you **MUST NOT** do is the following:

```
function dontDoIt(doSync) {
  if (doSync) return false;
  return Promise.resolve(false)
}
```

Why? Because:

- if `doSync` is truhtly, it will return false (i.e a boolean)
- if `doSync` is falsy, it will return a `Promise` that will resolve to false.

That is a HUGE difference.

Why?

Your function sometimes returns a promise, and other times return a boolean. It is inconsistent.

- doSync(true) is a boolean, you can't use await nor .then.
- doSync(false) is a Promise, you can use await and then.

Comment: I know that this code will work. But is it good to write sync code in async function? According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/22286961/9363390 I shouldn't write sync code in async function

Comment: Updated my answer. TLDR; if you use `async` keyword, it is okay. When you don't, you could have inconsistency problems. And btw, the problem of consistence pointed by the author of your linked answer is not a problem when you use `async` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct. There is no need to force anything to async if there doesn't need to be. Context switching isn't free, so if it doesn't have to wait for anything to complete, don't try and make it.