# How to identify an Asynchronous function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am new to Javascript and Asynchronous programing.

I have learnt that

1. Callbacks of an asynchronous function are put in a message queue and executed via event loop
2. Asynchronous execution is non-blocking, done via event loop.
3. Functions like `setTimeout` are asynchronous.
4. Asyncrhonous functions are blocking, only their callbacks are non-blocking

How to identify an Asynchronous function in Javascript ? and do "Asynchronous execution, non-blocking execution, execution context put in message queue" mean the same in Javascript ?

Please do point out if my learnings include misfacts

**Note** : I know about a similar question [What makes a JavaScript function asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50050540/what-makes-a-javascript-function-asynchronous), but the answers explain the mechanism and not "How to identify an Asynchronous function ?"

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. 3. Yes. 4. No.

Comment: "*do "Asynchronous execution, non-blocking execution, execution context put in message queue" mean the same in Javascript*" - there is an overlap but I would say "no" because they describe different aspects of execution, they aren't synonymous of *one* thing. Although, an asynchronous function often possesses all these qualities.

Comment: @VLAZ > 1. No. 2. No. 3. Yes. 4. No  Can you please elaborate ? I am new to Javascript and it is not so obvious, such conceptual misunderstandings are hampering my progress.