# How to create custom asynchronous function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I know that to create an asynchronous function all we need is to call an asynchronous function inside it like `setTimeout()` and passing a callback.

But how to create that natively without using any prebuilt function to achieve that ?

I know that functions that query a database have an asynchronous behavior, how do they do that without using something like `setTimeout()` in their original implementation ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create custom asynchronous functions in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22286887/1048572)

Comment: can you elaborate the exact usecase and what do you want to achieve out of that?

Comment: @Bergi I want to understand how to build a code that can be called and doesn't block the rest of the code. (without setTimeout like database queries functions does)

Comment: You could do this with Async await

Comment: @YoussefMohamed I repeat (from my answer): you cannot do that. I assume that you count the solution "putting the code in a worker process" as "using any prebuilt function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how to create that natively without using any prebuilt function to achieve that?

You cannot.

> I know that functions that query a database have an asynchronous behavior, how do they do that without using something like setTimeout() in their original implementation?

They usually will connect to the database using a network or filesystem socket, and for those there are builtin asynchronous functions (calling a callback when a response is received etc) that they build upon.

For node.js specifically, there is of course also the possibility of writing an [addon](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) to the engine itself that supplies such a "natively asynchronous" function to the JavaScript environment.

Answer (score 0):

Such functions usually aren't written **in** JavaScript.

They are usually written in the same programming language as the runtime engine and then plugged into it and exposed *as* a JavaScript function.

This is why if you were to run `XMLHttpRequest.toString()` in a browser, you'll get `"function XMLHttpRequest() { [native code] }"` and not the actual code of the function.